# sqs does not give me MessageAttributes when receiving message

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs

I have written the following API to recieve message :

```
app.get('/receive', function(req, res) {
    var params = {
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        VisibilityTimeout: 600
    };

    sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log('data is ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The response that I get is as follows:

```
{
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "id"
    },
    "Messages": [
        {
            "MessageId": "id",
            "ReceiptHandle": "handle",
            "MD5OfBody": "body",
            "Body": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

.

the send message format for the API is as shown below:

```
 let params = {
                       MessageBody: object,
                       QueueUrl: process.env.queueUrl,
                        MessageAttributes:{
                           "Title":{
                               DataType:'String',
                               StringValue:'Item Id Array',
                           }
                        },
                       DelaySeconds: 0
                   }
                   sqs.send(params, (err, data) => {
                       console.log('------------the send message data is------------',err,data);
                   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must tell SQS which attributes you want to receive in the params passed to `receiveMessage` function.

So in your case `params` definition in `/receive` route may look like this:

```
var params = {
    QueueUrl: queueUrl,
    VisibilityTimeout: 600,
    MessageAttributeNames: ["All"],
};
```

Check out the following links for more info:

1. [JavaScript SQS Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html#sqs-examples-send-receive-messages-receiving)
2. "Calling the receiveMessage operation" example in the [AWS JavaScript SDK doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html)
3. "MessageAttributeName.N" parameter in the [AWS SQS API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html)

Answer (score 1):

To receive all SQS attributes -> `.attributeNames(QueueAttributeName.ALL)`

To Receive message metadata attributes -> `.messageAttributeNames("yourMessageAttributeName")`

**Java/Kotlin**

```
 val request = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
                .queueUrl(url)                
                .messageAttributeNames("yourMessageAttributeName")
                .attributeNames(QueueAttributeName.ALL)
                .build()
        val messages = client.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).messages()
```